# How do I fuzzy match just adjacent cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I have a row of 10,000 names in two corresponding columns, 10,000 in each. Each cell in Column A corresponds to the adjacent cell in Column B. I want to do a fuzzy match and get a compatibility score on all of them just with the adjacent cell. I do not want it to search entire column versus entire column, just adjacent cells, which I don't seem to be able to do with the Fuzzy Match Excel add in, ideas?

Example:

```
Column A:       Column B:        Value:
Apple           Aplle            80%
Banana          Banana           100%
Orange          Ornge            85%
```

Comment: How would you like the values in the third column to be calculated??

Comment: Hi, I just want a confidence score as to how similar the names are? Some may be an exact match others may be completely different. Exactly like the Fuzzy Match tool but I don't think I can set that to just do adjacent cells, it only calculates column versus column. Thanks!

Comment: This would be pretty convoluted with formulas; a non-vba solution would probably need a number of helper columns equal to the max number of letters being compared. I doubt that's what you're looking for. The problem is that you want Apple to show as only 1 letter off when the 'p' is changed to 'l', but you want Orange to show as only 1 letter off when a letter is missing [I believe these is simply Levenshtein distance]. It would be difficult to show that Orange is not 4 letters different using Excel formulas, if one simply compares them letter by letter.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know about Fuzzy Match Addin but you can accomplish similar to your requirement using UDF.

Something like this based on your sample data

```
Function FuzzyComparision(String1 As String, String2 As String) As Double
Dim intStringLength As Integer
Dim dblScore As Double
Dim dblUnitScore As Double
Dim intCounter As Integer

intStringLength = WorksheetFunction.Max(Len(String1), Len(String2))
dblUnitScore = 1 / intStringLength
dblScore = 0#

For intCounter = 1 To intStringLength
    If Mid(UCase(String1), intCounter, 1) = Mid(UCase(String2), intCounter, 1) Then
        dblScore = dblScore + dblUnitScore
    Else
        If Len(String1) <> Len(String2) And intCounter < intStringLength Then
            If Mid(UCase(String1), intCounter + 1, 1) = Mid(UCase(String2), intCounter, 1) Then
                dblScore = dblScore + dblUnitScore
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

FuzzyComparision = dblScore
End Function
```

Of course the comparison can be further improvised as required.
Let me know if that helps

Edit: as Grade Bacon pointed (thanks for that observation), this does not work as expected for missing letters. I have tweaked the function a bit to do a case insensitive comparison and compensate for missing letters as in example.

Even though it works, utility depends on acceptable score deviation +/-. OP may shed some light.

Comment: Works nice. +1 for quality and effort.

Comment: Does this actually work for the case where a letter is removed from one of the words? See his "Orange" above - it shows that only 1 letter is expected to be 'taken off' from 100%. Under your method, wouldn't it count 4 differences, starting from the missing letter?

Answer (score 2):

Import this VBA module: https://github.com/kyledeer-32/vba_fuzzymatching

It contains several Fuzzy Matching UDFs - the one your specifically looking for is **=String_Similarity**. It will give you the match percentage between two strings. You can also use **=Fuzzy_Match** for matching one string (one cell) to an array of cells (one column).

Here are my results using applying this VBA module to your example data:

[image]

Here is a formula view:

[image]

Note: after importing this module, you will need to enable the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library in the Visual Basic Editor Window it to run. Steps to do this (takes less than a minute):

From Excel Workbook:

- Select Developer tab on ribbon
- Select Visual Basic
- Select Tools on the Toolbar
- Select References
- Scroll down until you see Microsoft Scripting Runtime, then check the
  box
- Press OK